# Plot data from two different data frames but keep the same size for point aesthetic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot:

[image]

which I got by executing the following command:

```
ggplot() + 
  stat_summary( data = cellBlocksUtilizationUl_lteOnly, aes(x=roundedRealNumVehicles/2, y=(value), colour=as.factor(1), lty=as.factor(1) ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=1 ) +
  stat_summary( data = cellBlocksUtilizationUl_lteOnly, aes(x=roundedRealNumVehicles/2, y=(value), colour=as.factor(1)  ) , fun.y=mean, geom="point", pch=21, fill="white", size=2 ) +
  stat_summary( data = cellBlocksUtilizationUl_clust, aes(x=roundedRealNumVehicles/2, y=(value), colour=as.factor(2), size=as.factor(clusteringDistance), lty=as.factor(2) ) , fun.y=mean, geom="line" ) +
  stat_summary( data = cellBlocksUtilizationUl_clust, aes(x=roundedRealNumVehicles/2, y=(value), colour=as.factor(2), size=as.factor(clusteringDistance) )  , fun.y=mean, geom="point", pch=21, fill="white" ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(2,1) ) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14, base_family = "Palatino") + 
  theme(legend.key = element_blank())
```

Note that the data is coming from two distinct data frames.

**How can I have the dots appearing on the whole plot to be of the same size?**

Is that possible without altering the data?

Comment: remove `size=as.factor(clusteringDistance)`?

Comment: try `group=as.factor(clusteringDistance)` in the fourth `stat_summary` call

Comment: it worked! please answer the question so I accept it. Also I would be extremely thankful if you can describe what `group` does in `aes`

Comment: its basically the same as what @mts said, so he/she should just add that to the answer their answer.  When you specified the `size` it automatically grouped the data, but then also used the values to determine the point sizes.  The `group` just does that without adding an aesthetic.  Oh, and in general, grouping just means your applying the functions to groups of the data (specified by factors) rather than all the data (eg. grand mean)

Comment: @nongkrong please go ahead and answer, your suggestion and explanation is much more complete, I deleted my answer as I don't have time for a thorough check.